# Using a dictionary that looks like {'x':'y'} to look for 'x' in column A, if found, replace it with value 'y' in column B

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

Here's my df:

```
data = {'Country':['France', 'Spain', 'Japan', 'South Korea', 'South Africa', 'Egypt'],
   'Region':['', 'Europe', '', 'Asia', '', 'Africa']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I also have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
'France':'Europe',
'Spain':'Europe',
'Japan':'Asia',
'South Korea':'Asia',
'South Africa':'Africa',
'Egypt':'Africa'}
```

**My goal is to fill in the blanks in the 'Region' column in the dataframe, using the pairs contained in the dictionary.**

I've tried multiple things, the latest one being:

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
df.replace({'Country':{k:my_dict[k]}}, inplace=True)
```

but nothing gets replaced.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(my_dict)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I didn't know about .map() . Thanks!